# How to remove all items from the Virtual Arsenal in SQF?

Tags: sqf

I have been using

```
["AmmoboxInit",[_ammoBox, false,{true}]] call BIS_fnc_arsenal;
```

to initialize the arsenal empty. However, if I re-run this command, it will not re-empty the arsenal.

I could use `BIS_fnc_removeVirtual*Cargo` to remove each item there, but is there a way that allows me to remove *everything* from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the Virtual Cargo using this line

`_ammoBox setvariable ["bis_addVirtualWeaponCargo_cargo",nil,_true];`

This will remove everything you added using the BIS_fnc_addVirtual*Cargo calls. So that should make your Arsenal empty.

Or optionally you could completly remove the Arsenal using:

`["AmmoboxExit",_ammoBox] call bis_fnc_arsenal;`
and then re-add it again.

Comment: Just to check, `"bis_addVirtualWeaponCargo_cargo"` is for the weapons, and the same applies to the others (e.g. `"bis_addVirtualMagazineCargo_cargo"`), right?

Comment: No. Everything is stored in that one Variable. Don't ask me why though. It's just Arma ^^

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can loop over [`BIS_fnc_addVirtualItemCargo`](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/BIS_fnc_addVirtualItemCargo) to remove elements of each types, this is the only way I've found to remove the elements and avoid adding the *"Arsenal"* action to the Virtual Arsenal (which was the player in my case)

```
#define ITEMS_TYPE 0
#define WEAPONS_TYPE 1
#define MAGAZINES_TYPE 2
#define BACKPACKS_TYPE 3
#define ACTION_REMOVE -1
#define ACTION_GET 0
#define ACTION_ADD 1
#define ADD_GLOBAL true
#define ADD_ARSENAL_ACTION true

for "_elementType" from ITEMS_TYPE to BACKPACKS_TYPE do 
{
    // Use an empty array as second argument to remove the elements when using ACTION_REMOVE
    [
        _ammoBox,
        [],
        ADD_GLOBAL,
        !ADD_ARSENAL_ACTION,
        ACTION_REMOVE,
        _elementType
    ] call BIS_fnc_addVirtualItemCargo;
};
```